# do text ads count as backlinks?

Tags: links, backlinks, text, anchor

Do text link ads, like the ones from [text-link-ads.com](http://www.text-link-ads.com/) act as backlinks ? Surly they work as normal anchor text, but are search engines wise to this technique and just not count them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it will act as back links ,even you can sometime see in google webmaster tool as back links but **BEWARE . Google will punish you for excessive paid back links or link exchanges** .

this what google say about paid back links

> " Buying or selling links that pass PageRank is in violation of Google's Webmaster Guidelines and can negatively impact a site's ranking in search results."

so if you are looking for better Google ranking or Google's page Rank  better stick to normal and safe way to build genuine back links from high rated websites and from sites which have better page ranks .

Comment: surly that stance from google is open to HUGE abuse, i could just build thousands of 'spammy' links for my competitors to get there rankings reduced ?

Comment: @sam are you talking about " Negative SEO "

Comment: i havnt come accross the term "negative SEO" before - is that where you build links to sabotage a site ?

Comment: @sam yes - it is very negative way to improve your site  ranking - unethical technique  to  improve your own rankings by downgrading your competitor’s sites

Comment: how can you protect against it, if someones "attacking" your site with negative backlinks ?

Comment: sam ,Google Webmaster Tools will alert you if something malicious or unusual happens to your site that you should be aware of. It is also useful to contact Google with if you notice effects of potential Negative SEO ( spammy back links appears in web master page that you are not worked for) & inform them that it is not coming from you.

Answer (score 1):

According to Matt Cutts (the Google alter ego) the url text with no link it does not count as link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlByfISlj5w